# Azure can not access VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have created a VM via terraform but I can not access it from https://shell.azure.com/

When I type:

```
ssh azureuser@40.IP.IP.IP
```

I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

From terraform script I know that this VM was created with:

```
os_profile {
    computer_name  = "myvm"
    admin_username = "azureuser"
}

os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = true
    ssh_keys {
        path     = "/home/azureuser/.ssh/authorized_keys"
        key_data = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nz(...)"
    }
}
output "public_ip_address" {
    value = azurerm_public_ip.myterraformpublicip.ip_address
}
```

How can I access my VM? I know it's IP, admin user but can not access it.

On Azure in `/home/user/.ssh` I got a public key and a private key.

Comment: Have you configured the firewall to allow access from your IP addresses?

Comment: Did you write the ssh key in the Azure cloud shell?

Comment: I get public key on Azure server in `/home/user/.ssh`
I managed to access ubuntu via this command other day.

Comment: Does the key in `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa` on Azure server has to be the same as in terraform script? Currently it is not the same

Comment: Yes, it must be the same so that you can ssh the VM from the host where you execute the terraform, here is the cloud shell.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I posted answer. To be exact the `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` must be the same not the `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Answer (score 1):

Azure has option for changing ssh key or password:
[image]

I used it and passed here key generated on https://shell.azure.com/
with command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
```

Then command:

```
ssh azureuser@40.IP.IP.IP
```

worked fine.

The public key `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` must be the same as in the `VM`.

Comment: What you really wanted to do is SSH in to the VM and 'add' public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, so cloudshell and the system template was created for could ssh. Reseting key removed the other key, if the same username was used.

Comment: I could not access VM - so how could i add public key to it? As i posted in question terraform added public key on initialization of my VM. But when i used it it was not the correct one.

Comment: You should review the Terraform steps again, it should have a Private key or ask you to use your own public key during deployment.

Comment: Well yeah, i provided this in the question here: `key_data = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nz(...)"` but it did not work for some reasons.

Comment: So if you provided the public key it means you have the private key.  You could have used the private key with putty or even add it to the CloudShell to gain access to the VM.

Comment: This public key was not valid. If public key is not valid then i guess that private key was also invalid. And it was added to CloudShell.

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, I think there would be two possible reasons, maybe what you have done solve the problem, but it should be the last way.

Here are the possible reasons and solutions:

1. The SSH key is not the same as which you used to create the VM in the host that you want to ssh to the VM from (for you is the cloud shell).

**Solution:** You need to copy the SSH key from the terraform file into the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file in the host (for you is the cloud shell).

2. The SSH key is not in the right format, it means it's the wrong key.

**Solution:** You need to create a new SSH key and then reset the VM SSH public key with the new key as you did.

Comment: I tried point 1 before going to step 2. But step 2. helped me and i posted it as an answer to this question. Still an upvote from me - this was what i did.

Comment: @tryingHard Well, I post the possible reasons for this problem. Maybe it will help others. If you think it's OK, you can accept it as the answer. If you think it's just helpful but not the solution you need, then an upvote is also OK.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below command which explicitly specifies which key to use. [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/37692)

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa azureuser@yourpublicip
```